# Do we want questions about scams, phising and malware?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I just saw the area51 proposal [scams-phishing-and-malware](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23359/scams-phishing-and-malware). Dont we want questions like these on our SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is based around either actual security measures, or business risk analysis...
AND if it's not about your grandmother getting scammed at home...
AND if it's not about "help i got phished quick what do i do"
AND if its more about "business" security -

Then, yes there is room for it here.
However, I do think its a fine line...

Answer (score 1):

Well the proposed site includes non-computer related scams and seems to be focused on the end-user side of things. If the question is "how do I protect my customers from scams, phishing, and malware?" then it would still be better asked here than there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AviD.  Their proposal appears to be about protecting ones self from identity theft.  We can learn from them and they can learn from us, but it looks like a different area/emphasis.